# Google Maps Flutter - White Screen Issue Despite Correct API Key Setup

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to integrate Google Maps into my Flutter app using the google_maps_flutter package. Despite correctly setting up the API keys for both iOS and Android according to the official documentation, I am encountering a persistent issue where the map displays a white screen instead of the expected map view.

Here is a simplified version of my code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

class MapScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static String id = 'map';
  const MapScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<MapScreen> createState() => _MapScreenState();
}

class _MapScreenState extends State<MapScreen> {
  late GoogleMapController mapController;

  final LatLng _center = const LatLng(45.521563, -122.677433);

  void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
    mapController = controller;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        useMaterial3: true,
        colorSchemeSeed: Colors.green[700],
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Maps Sample App'),
          elevation: 2,
        ),
        body: GoogleMap(
          myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
          zoomControlsEnabled: false,
          onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
          initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
            target: _center,
            zoom: 11.0,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have double-checked my API keys, and they seem to be configured correctly. However, the map remains blank. Has anyone experienced a similar issue or can provide insights into potential solutions? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I tried connecting to google maps and since I didn't get any errors I expected to see the map

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Have you tried contacting support? If not, I'd suggest that you do so that Tech agents can take a look and see if there's any issue with your project that might have been causing this. https://developers.google.com/maps/support#contact-maps-support